# No Display Port output & hardware acceleration when using Loki on a Mac Mini 2011

Tags: release-loki, graphics, radeon

I installed Loki successfully on a Mac Mini 2011 a couple of days ago. Everything is working fine, but hardware acceleration (which I don't need) and the Display Port output (which I do need).

That's what `lshw -C video` gives me:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a8800000-a881ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:a8820000-a883ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a8000000-a83fffff memory:a0000000-a7ffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

And `glxgears -info` says:

```
GL_RENDERER   = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
GL_VENDOR     = VMware, Inc.
```

The radeon driver is installed, but if I understand correctly, not used. I don't care about the driver I'm using, as long as I can attach a second screen.

Any ides on what to do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this in a virtual machine (VMware)?

Comment: No, it's not. It's elementary booted on a Mac Mini. What makes you think that's a virtual machine? The `llvmpipe`? I think that's because I'm booting with `nomodeset`, because everything else gives me a black screen. Apart from installing the amdgpu pro driver, which makes the system horribly slow and characters appear in > 15 seconds after I pressed them.

Comment: What is the resolution / model of the monitor attached to the Display Port / Thunderbolt output? Maybe this helps: https://nsrc.org/workshops/2015/nsrc-icann-dns-ttt-dubai/raw-attachment/wiki/Agenda/install-ubuntu-mac-mini.htm#problems-with-video (P.S.: Very good and detailed first question ;) )

Comment: The display is 1600x1200 connected via a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter. And thanks for the link! Sadly, I'm already using nomodeset, which might be part of the problem, because as far as I understand radeon needs kernel mode setting in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a 2011 mini. I had to use nomodeset as well, but decided to install refind boot manager to make customizing boot options easier. With it I was able to get the mini to boot without nomodeset and without proprietary drivers. Whistler is workin well for me. I haven't tried two monitors at once but I have tried both hdmi and the mini display port. Both are working.